# Execute stack after cloudFormation Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a *ApiGateway* made with Serverless-model-application that I made a integration with *GitHub* via *CodePipeline*, everything is running fine, the pipeline reads the webhook, builds the `buildpsec.yml` and deploys the *CloudFormation* file, creating the updating the stack.

The thing is after the stack is updated it still needs a approval on the console, how can I make the execute on the stack update be auto-run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `pipeline` is doing one of two things, unless I'm misunderstanding you:

1. Making a change set but not executing it in the cloudformation console.
2. Proceeding to a manual approval step in the pipeline and awaiting your confirmation.

Since #2 is simply solved by removing that step, let's talk about #1.

Assuming you are successfully creating a change set called `ChangeSetName`, you need a step in your pipeline with the following (cfn JSON template syntax):

```
"Name": "StepName",
"ActionTypeId": {"Category": "Deploy",
                 "Owner": "AWS",
                 "Provider": "CloudFormation",
                 "Version": "1"
                                },
                 "Configuration": {
                 "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE",
                 "ChangeSetName": {
                 "Ref": "ChangeSetName"
                                    },
                 ...
```

Keep the other parameters (e.g. RoleArn) consistent per usual.

Comment: Which one was it @DanielBezerraDeMenezes ?

Comment: The first one, i added an extra step in the pipeline with the change set execute.